# Are there any concerns swapping bios chips (same model)?

Tags: motherboard, bios

So, I know the bios chip is removable, or removable on some boards at least, and you can get replacement ones if you do something to fry/brick your current bios. Am just wondering how "safe" the swap process is, since under the above scenario, you're already in failure conditions so most people's risk/reward is different at that point.

If there's lesser reasons* where you have two functioning motherboards and want to swap chips between them, is there any serious concerns about something going wrong with either one, or are you fine so long as you don't fail any of the physical aspects of the process (damage chip/board during removal/placement)?

*Relatively obscure problem unrelated to the more general question

Comment: well, as long as they target the EXACT same motherboard, it should work, but you would want to immediately flash up to the latest. if your CPU came to be supported in a later revision of your bios (I have a couple boards with CPUs that were not supported by the first commercial version of the bios) and the new chips version is below that, it may not be possible to boot or upgrade the BIOS version.  As for actually removing and attaching a new chip, I don't think I;ve seen a motherboard with a removable cockroach chip in many years. I think they are soldered in these days.